# Equivalent of GMSCoordinateBounds in MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

After choosing a location, a pin is dropped in a `mapView`.

```
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(placemark.coordinate, span)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

I want to zoom to the bounding region of the placemark using Apple's MapKit. i.e I want the `span` to depend on the bounding region of the place.
This is doable using Google Maps SDK, 
but using Google's Places pod adds too much to the file size of the app (+ increases the app load time)

how to do This using MapKit and Swift?